# NAudio - seeking and navigation to play from the specified position

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm using NAudio library in a C# application. I'm trying to seek an audio (*.mp3 file) to the position I want.
However I didn't figure out how to do it.

```
//Play the file starting from 16th second
waveStream.Seek(16, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

And ... It played starting almost from  the beginning, but not from the 16th second. I also found a solution I thought true:

```
waveStream.Seek(waveStream.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 16, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

It seems it's closer the truth. Is my resolving true or not? If not what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `Position` directly on a `WaveStream`, which must be converted into a byte offset - so yes, multiplying the average bytes per second by the number of seconds will get you to the right place (at least with regular PCM WAV files). `WaveStream` also has a helper property called `CurrentTime` allowing you to use a `TimeSpan` and it does the same calculation for you.

`audioFile.Position += audioFile.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 15;`

Answer (score 9):

If someone still has this problem and can not figure it out.
Then here is an example:

```
myWaveStream.CurrentTime = myWaveStream.CurrentTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds));

myWaveStream.CurrentTime = myWaveStream.CurrentTime.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out!

Comment: That’s it. For some reason, the `ISampleProvider`’s extension method `Skip()` (that should take the same `TimeSpan`) doesn’t work, but this calculation approach does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I created a navigation using a trackBar with 4 ticks per second (1 tick at 250ms):

```
trackBar1.Maximum = (int)stream.TotalTime.TotalSeconds * 4;
```

In a timer tick handler, called at each 250ms, an update of the trackbar is done as following:

```
double ms = stream.Position * 1000.0 / output.OutputWaveFormat.BitsPerSample / output.OutputWaveFormat.Channels * 8.0 / output.OutputWaveFormat.SampleRate;
trackBar1.Value = (int) (4 * ms / 1000);
```

In order to set the position (after scrolling), this formula worked:

```
double ms = trackBar1.Value * 1000.0 / 4.0;
stream.Position = (long)(ms * output.OutputWaveFormat.SampleRate * output.OutputWaveFormat.BitsPerSample * output.OutputWaveFormat.Channels / 8000.0) & ~1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Winforms Trackbar Min=0 Max=100 (see Mark Heath answere the owner of the Naudio- Lib):

```
    private void TrkbrPosition_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (audioFile != null)
        {
            var lengthInBytes = audioFile.Length;
            var pos = (lengthInBytes/100) * TrkbrPosition.Value;
            audioFile.Position = pos;
        }
    }
```